# Will utilizing the "Show" in iOS storyboard cause an iOS app to crash?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

**Summary:**

I'm writing a Swift iOS app with a login screen and several other views in a tab view controller. I'm transitioning from one viewcontroller to another via the "control" + left click -> "Show" method. I want to make sure I'm not designing my iOS app incorrectly with memory leaks or other flaws.

**Relative Questions:**

- Does this mean a new view of that ViewController is created each time "Show" is called?
- Could this cause a memory leak or the app to crash?
- Do I need to unwind the ViewControllers at some point?
- What is the best way to unwind a ViewController when launching another ViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you are talking about is manually creating a Show Segue (a transition, made via the Storyboard with ctrl + click and drag to another ViewController). This is one correct way to create a Segue (transition) from one ViewController to another. To utilize this, you will need to use the left panel on the Storyboard, give this segue an identifier, and use this identifier to preform a segue from the first ViewController to the second in some sort of method or action (like a button click, etc) using the performSegue method:

`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NameOfSegue", sender: self)`

Here's more info on segues from the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html

You can read even more detail in the "Modifying a Segue’s Behavior at Runtime" section. Here's a quote: "Most of the work happens in the presenting view controller, which manages the transition to the new view controller. The configuration of the new view controller follows essentially the same process as when you create the view controller yourself and present it." Memory leaks shouldn't be an issue here. Unwind segues let you dismiss view controllers that have been presented, but they are not always needed.